# Shelf life of a new HDD

Tags: hard-drive, nas

I just bought a few hard drives (WD Black WD2003FYPS, the sticker also says "Enterprise Storage" on it) that were all individually wrapped in a sealed anti-static bag when I got them shipped in the usual packaging.

[image]

*(not the actual packaging)

Through the bag I can read that they have a date from 2010 on them and I was wondering if there is a shelf life to new hard drives, that (presumably) haven't been used before. I am planning on using them in a NAS build that does have redundancy but I wouldn't want to use drives that have aged too much already, since I still have the chance to return them, if it turns out to be a bad idea to use them.

Comment: HDD does not expire.  If the drive is not used, because it is a mechanical device, its lifespan only decreases while in use.

Comment: Your hardware does not suffer from age by sitting unused on shelves. The only concern one would have by letting hardware sit unused for 6 years is the hardware becoming "out of date." That's not so much of a worry with HDD's, but it's not something I would do with a CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about shelf life, particularly with enterprise drives, if they have been kept in sealed bags with a moisture absorbing packet inside.  I have working 20-yr old server drives, they're loud but work fine :)

However, if they have only "presumably" never been used before I would open up only one of the drives and then use a SMART reader to check for any past activity or number of hours the drive was powered on.  Personally I use  [PassMark's DiskCheckup](http://www.passmark.com/products/diskcheckup.htm).

FYI: some USB-to-SATA dongles don't play well with SMART, you may have to plug the drive onto a spare on-board connector to read its status.

Comment: I connected one of them to my desktop PC and from what I could tell the drives were really never used before. The power on counter was set to one, which I assume was me trying it out. But they actually didn't come with a silica packet in the anti-static bag. Are some drives shipped from the manufacturer without them?

Comment: Some manufacturers may not have the packet in the bag itself but somewhere in the box/packaging.  Some have a packet inside the drive (one would have to remove the cover to see it).